# AngularJS ng-repeat filter to child node

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following JSON data structure

```
{ "firstName" : "John",
  "role" : "Manager",
  "status" : {
                "Id" : 30,
                "Status" : "Appointment booked",
                "statusDate" : 1467826508775
             },
  "surname" : "Smith",
  "title" : "Mr",
}
```

and I am trying to use an ng-repeat with a filter to the second level node status.Status. I have tried the following but the filter does not work.

```
ng-repeat="data in data | filter: {status.Status: 'Appointment booked'}"
```

Is the above possible on ng-repeat or do I need to look at an alternative solution?

Comment: Try `filter: {status: { Status: 'Appointment booked'} }"`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I have been scratching my head on this one for most of the day. If you put it down as an answer I will mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: make this an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a custom filter when all else fails:

```
ng-repeat="d in data | myFormat"
```

JS:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        "firstName": "John",
        "role": "Manager",
        "status": {
            "Id": 30,
            "Status": "Appointment booked",
            "statusDate": 1467826508775
        },
        "surname": "Smith",
        "title": "Mr",
    }
});

app.filter('myFormat', function () {
    return function (x) {
        if (x.status.Status == 'Appointment booked') {
            return x;
        }
    };
});
```

As mentionned in comments

```
ng-repeat="d in data | filter : {status: { Status : 'Apointment booked'}}"
```

works aswell

Comment: I have used the solution in the comment from @Italo Ayres but I will mark this as the correct answer as it has given me an insight into the flexibility of the custom filter.